# Dynamics Crm 4.0 - Find when email template was last used

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I am trying to clean up all the old email templates in our Crm database. Is there a way to find when A template was last used to create an email?

I've looked through the database tables but cant see to find anything.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's unlikely you're going to get an answer to this question, although it's a good one, since templates are inserted inside the email, not related to the actual message itself. In fact, I believe they operate in a very Javascript/XSLT fashion, so I don't think it likely there is much evidence in the database. Templates leave a bit to be desired in CRM 4, since they can't be enabled/disabled either, thus you can't turn them off for a bit to see if anyone notices.

If you truly need to know this information, you could override the system javascript to update a record on a  custom entity whenever a template is selected, but honestly that's a risky, unsupported, and fairly invasive customization that could be more easily achieved by emailing users and asking. Hope you find a solution that fits your needs.